# unable to fire event $.mobile.changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

up to now, I still haven't figured out why the $.mobile.changePage won't fire in next/second page, it only works in the index page. I get it that using jquery mobile all script will be only loaded once because jqm is built in ajax way. But I still can't find a solution to my problem.

This script below don't fire if not in the index.page or first load.

```
            $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
            $('.sns-down').bind('swipe', function(event) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"});
            });
        });
```

I made a simple demo and I attached it here for more clarification.
[Download Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?2lzu34cb19y62bw)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use $(document).bind, use the new `on` delegation, this places a listener at your document root which listens to pageinit/pageshow events that bubble up when new pages are added by jQM.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', 'div:jqmData(role="page"), div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function(event){
        $(this).find('.sns-down').bind('swipe', function(event) {
            $.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"});
        });
```

Don't use a straight `$('.sns-down')` this selector may inadvertently select elements not within your current page, you should always search from the current page.

Next thing to check is if `#featured` exists, if you included it in your first page then it'll be there. If your second page is a multi-page template and you link to it, jQM only pulls in the single page from your multi-page template. Just try an actual page to rule this issue out.

Use a debugger/alert to ensure that pageinit is caught properly by the page transition to rule that out, but it should work.

Comment: morning, i'll test this right away. hope it will work now. ^_^

Comment: what do you mean by try an actual page? I think that's my issue here. In my second page I have a multi-page/ 2 data-role=page. @_@

Comment: You can't do that, you see when jQM loads a <div data-role="page"> from a multi page template it ONLY grabs that one page, everything between the `<div data-role="page">` it completely ignores any other pages you have on the page AND any JS included in the <head> tags. Which is a good thing to remember, this means "all" your JS needs to be on any entry point to your site. In my case every page includes the JS I need just once, subsequent pages load no new JS.

Comment: Move your #featured page, into a separate file, then change to that page and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i did to solve this. thanks clay. in behalf of my family, i salute you :P

Answer (score 1):

Hiya probably this might give you an idea you can copy paste the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/r4DyU/1/

Can you jsfiddle yours but above should help.

cheers!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/x3TA6/ - I've put all necessary code. But unable to run it. Coz, I have 3 files and I used a swipe event. Can jsfiddle handles this? Try my download link for more information

Comment: hiya few recommendation for jsfiddle to remove few errors **1)** with the jsfiddle I reckon test1 and 2.php is not there so delete them **2)** there is not class .sns-down in the html , I will see the link you got thank! ** update: Never used the download site you mentioned bit cautious man jsfiddle will be awesome if you can :)

Comment: ok, will wait for your response. hope you can find a way to fix it